# AWS ECS- Task exited automatically with an exit code 0

Tags: docker, containers, microservices, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I am trying to run 1 service in AWS ECS where I am getting "**essential container in task exited exit code 0**" as error .

While checking the logs , i don't see any logs also

Troubleshooting done:

1. Checked in cloud watch/logs/insights on logs (missing)
2. Tried to deploy another service as container (running successfully)
3. Tried to deploy the same container manually in ECS instance (running successfully)
4. Tried with changing Task definition and changing cluster (Not working)

Still only for this 1 service, am getting the same error again and again.
While checking for logs also , Am not able to get the logs.

**Can anyone suggest what to do here?**

The below shows an example of the error .

[image]

Comment: It's hard to figure out the reason. From what you are showing there is a container that has terminated its program and so the container has exited (and so did the task). This could happen by design. For example I just note incidentally that the task def name is `curler`. If the command your container runs at start is `curl` then you should expect it to exit (because curl runs and stops). Maybe if you could post the task def + Dockerfile we could get more hints.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved.

Was having issue with environment variables , as it was not loading in docker container.

Hence container got up and drains out

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found out the issue for your use case.
The exit code 0 usually indicates that the container was stopped due to any possible reason which may include the error in the code .As we all know containers are nothing but processes so once the process ends the containers kill themselves.

So if your application is not starting (which is also a kind of process) then the container would kill itself.

Here are some possible reasons:

1. The application failed to start.
2. The health check failed in the container.
3. The container is consuming too much resources because of which it is explicitly killed by the ECS .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).